# Can I approach a new professor from another University?

Tags: graduate-school, changing-fields

I am a Masters student.
After two years of research, I could not able to meet the standard of my professor.
I have tried a lot but he said I am not good enough at writing papers. I would not be able to graduate. But I think I have research potential. I will lose my confidence if I woud not be able to finish my research.

Is it a good idea to approach a new professor by describing my current situation from another University and start over again?

Comment: Why "not good enough at writing papers" implies "not be able to graduate"?

Comment: As my department rule, to graduate, I have to publish paper or attend the conference at least three times.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misunderstand the rule?

Comment: My professor confirmed me the rule.

Comment: Maybe your supervisor misunderstood (or invented) the rule?

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is not being able to write, then that is the problem you need to tackle. Going to another university and starting over does not solve that problem.

Writing is something that can be learned. All the universities I have been had hat courses or workshops or other forms of help available. So that is what I would do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please tell me how can I get your help?

Comment: You can't. The point of my answer is that you have to look at the resources available at your own university.

Comment: Going to another supervisor might be part of the solution, however, since it is also the supervisor who should teach a student how to write papers, be it through direct feedback, or by providing students with resources and directions that allow them to learn it.